# Is there a more efficient way to write this Actionscript that calculate the results of a random "spin"?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3

This is a slot machine style simulation. I have 5 reels with 9 possible symbols on each wheel. The following is the code I came up with to calculate the payout of a given pay line. I have omitted the code that generates the random symbols. This code takes just the result of the randomization and determines what a player has won, if anything.

```
paytable[0] = [3,5,6,8,10,15,20,50,150];
paytable[1] = [12,15,20,30,50,80,100,200,1500];
paytable[3] = [50,75,100,150,200,250,500,2000,10000];
//symbol[0..4] is assigned a value of 0..8
//the value 8 is considered wild and will match any
//other symbol except when the first 3 on a line

payout = 0;
if(!(symb[0] == 8)){
    if(symb[1] == 8 || symb[1] == symb[0]){
        if(symb[2] == 8 || symb[2] == symb[0]){
            payout = paytable[0][symb[0]];
            if(symb[3] == 8 || symb[3] == symb[0]){
                payout = paytable[1][symb[0]];
                if(symb[4] == 8 || symb[4] == symb[0]){
                    payout = paytable[2][symb[0]];}}}}
} else if(!(symb[1] == 8)){
    if(symb[2] == symb[1]){
        payout = paytable[0][symb[1]];
        if(symb[3] == 8 || symb[3] == symb[1]){
            payout = paytable[1][symb[1]];
            if(symb[4] == 8 || symb[4] == symb[1]){
                payout = paytable[2][symb[1]];}}}
} else if(!(symb[2] == 8){
    payout = paytable[0][symb[2]];
    if(symb[3] == 8 || symb[3] == symb[2]){
        payout = paytable[1][symb[2]];
        if(symb[4] == 8 || symb[4] == symb[2]){
            payout = paytable[2][symb[2]];}}
} else {
    payout = paytable[0][8];
    if(symb[3] == 8){
        payout = paytable[1][8];
        if(symb[3] == 8){
            payout = paytable[2][8];}}
}
```

Just to be clear, the code works as expected I am just a novice wanting to make sure I'm not making some bone head algorithm mistake.

Comment: To answer your question: no, no issues with the performance of the code. It would really benefit from a renaming pass though (what is the importance of the number 8 for instance?) And then a refactoring pass to clean up duplicated code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a 2D array of matches with a special value, say -1, to mean "any", and check reels vs elements of that array row by row, once match is found, get payment from the same array (extra element) and award that.

```
static var wins:Array=[]; // one win set for class. Static to signify global data
wins.push([8,8,8,8,8,10000]);
wins.push([8,8,8,8,-1,1500]);
wins.push([8,8,8,-1,-1,150]);
// etc. Make sure more difficult or more precise matches are before less precise ones
```

Another way of writing such a structure:

```
static var wins:Array=[ 
    [8,8,8,8,8,10000],
    [8,8,8,8,-1,1500],
    [8,8,8,-1,-1,150],
    // etc, don't forget to not type a comma at the last entry
];
```

With this structure `wins` is a two-dimensional array which rows have elements 0-4 correspond to reels, and element 5 correspond to win value. So, then you traverse that array in turn, bailing out once a match is found.

```
function checkWin(reels:Array):int {
    // assuming reels to hold those 0-8 values
    for (var i:int=0;i<wins.length;i++) {
        var aWin:Array=wins[i];
        for (var j:int=0;j<5;j++) { // check reels vs aWin
            if ((aWin[j]!=reels[j]) && (aWin[j]>=0)) break; // no match
            if (j==4) return aWin[5]; // match! You win! :D
        }
    }
    return 0; // no match - no win.
}
```

Comment: At a minimum (I may have missed some combinations) `wins.length` will be 304. That's a lot of `push` statements to manage. Also, it seems the worst case scenario is hitting the outer loop 304 times whereas my example has a worst case scenario of evaluating 6 if statements. But like I said I'm a beginner so maybe you can shed some light.

Comment: 304 isn't too big if it comes to executing once per say 3-4 seconds. If you want, you can split `wins` by first reel, and run through only matching part of `wins`. About push statements, you can do a constant declaration syntax instead of pushes. Check updated answer.

Comment: Yes, the whole array way of writing your ifs is for maintainability, should you find out you've missed a winning condition, you add a line to `wins` declaration, and that's all, but to change your if statement tree will likely break it with this many branches and conditions.